# form taking too long to load due to dataset

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Actually my dataset source is mysql and this is my code

```
 private void frmNewInstallment_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'cricflip_RoyalResidencyDataSet.booked_homes' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.booked_homesTableAdapter.Fill(this.cricflip_RoyalResidencyDataSet.booked_homes);


        }
```

But still it's taking long to load that form i want to eliminate that delay. Is there any way to do this asynchronously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performing heavy operations in `Form_Load` event is not advisable, I would suggest using `thread/task` to do this operations.

```
private void frmNewInstallment_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Start a thread to load data asynchronously.
     Thread t = new Thread(LoadData);
     t.Start();
}  


private void LoadData()
{
     this.booked_homesTableAdapter.Fill(this.cricflip_RoyalResidencyDataSet.booked_homes);

    // Check if this code is executed on some other thread than UI thread
    if (InvokeRequired) // In this example, this will return `true`.
    {
        BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            // Update your UI controls.
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but after implementing this combobox remains empty

Comment: Place all your UI operations inside `BeginInvoke` block.

Comment: if (InvokeRequired) // In this example, this will return `true`.
            {
                BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    this.comboBox1.DataSource = this.bookedhomesBindingSource;
                    this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Client_name";
                    this.comboBox1.TabIndex = 0;
                    this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "Client_name";
                }));
            }

Comment: I guess your datasource should be `this.cricflip_RoyalResidencyDataSet.booked_homes`

Comment: Try using `this.comboBox1.DataSource = this.cricflip_RoyalResidencyDataSet.booked_homes`.

Comment: Thanks alot sir it's working great and fine and if possible then let me use any progress dialog to show progress upon this :)

Comment: Concept is same, create thread and start updating progressbar in other than any UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the form load event. Make a background worker, during the form load event, start the background worker. Have the background worker update the GUI, so users know it's still busy.

Example; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Sir can you make implementation for my code with background worker ? i'm actually newbie and if possible than add any progress bar or dialog

Comment: Nope, for you to grow from a newbie to a actual programmer, this would make a nice exercise. Spend a half hour actually reading the link. Or, wait, on the second thought, yup, I am willing to make an implementation for you,  my rate is 80 euro's per hour. PM me for details.

Comment: @Lectere Link only answers though aren't the best answers (even though I think your answer is appropriate. So, maybe a little bit of code could actually add value to the answer - not the implementation per say, but some code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need different thread for this. During loading data from database thread do nothing - only waiting for response from database.

With `async/await` approach you will use same UI thread which will be freed during waiting for response.

`Form.Load` eventhandler seems good enough place for this

Mark `Load` eventhandler as `async` and make your database call async too.

```
public async Task<DataTable> GetData()
{
    //Your load logic
}

private async void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ComboBox.DataSource = await GetData();
}
```

[Asynchronous Programming with async and await (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt674882.aspx)

async/await, as I understand, was designed exactly for IO processes.

You will need different threads only when your calculating/processing some data already in memory.